# loading image resources from dedicated dll in winapi c project

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-studio-2012, dll

I'm working on a win32 c++ project in vs2012.
My project uses a large number of resources like images, icons etc.
I've embedded those resources within the exe, those resources compiled.
I did it using the normal visual studio resource file.
It takes so much time compiling the project.
And the exe file was bulky.

So I decided to bring all those resources compiled to another dll file.
And lod it whenever the resource is required, and unload it.
My algorithm for that load resource function was like...

```
HBITMAP LoadMyImage (INT nResId)
{
    HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibrary (DLL_RESOURCE);
    if (hDll==NULL)
        return NULL;

    HBITMAP hBitmap = LoadImage (
        hDll, MAKEINTRESOURCE (nResId), IMAGE_BITMAP,
        LR_DEFAULTSIZE, LR_DEFAULTSIZE,
        LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
    if (hBitmap==NULL)
        return NULL;

    FreeLibrary (hLib);
    return hBitmap;
}
```

Is this a good way considering performance, convention and complexity?
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

In essence this is a sound approach. There are a couple of details that I feel should be improved:

1. Don't use `LoadLibrary` which is intended for libraries with code. Use `LoadLibraryEx` passing `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE | LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE`.
2. Don't load and unload the DLL repeatedly. Load it once when you first need an image. Loading modules does have a performance cost and you may as well pay that cost once only.

Comment: In fact, it is not even possible to load a resource-only DLL using `LoadLibrary`. Calling `LoadLibraryEx` is mandatory.

Comment: @IInspectable Out of interest, how do you go about building such a resource only DLL?

Comment: There's a guide in the MSDN: [Creating a Resource-Only DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24b2tcy0.aspx). I haven't created one myself, and don't know if DLLs created this way are truly resource-only DLLs (i.e. do not contain an entry point stub).